# Eclipse PDT equivalent for NetBeans PHP Ctrl+P inside function call parenthesis

Tags: eclipse-pdt

When I press Ctrl+P in NetBeans PHP while writing down function call parameters I get a tooltip reminding me of the parameters:
[image: netbeans screenshot]

Is there an equivalent for this in Eclipde PDT? It seems I can only get the autocomplete box while typing the function name - as soon as the cursor is in the function calls parenthesis there is no obvious way to get the autocomplete box again or anything like the tooltip above.

Ctrl+Space just gives me a list of local variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is! : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does something similar in PDT.
Get a list of all shortcuts by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: You're welcome! See the bonus shortcut above to get all shortcuts